# Slow Callback Processing for High-Frequency nav_msgs/Odometry Data

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, when I subscribed to nav_msgs/Odometry data which is published at a frequency of 100hz, the callback processed the data slowly and the data was lost. Even if it do nothing with the data, just print it to the screen. Here is my code, thanks. Details are below the code.

> subscriber.cpp

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h"

void Callback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr &data)
{
    ROS_INFO("x: %f", data->pose.pose.position.x);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "sub");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("data", 1, Callback);
    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

> publisher.cpp

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "pub");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry>("data", 1);
    nav_msgs::Odometry data;
    data.pose.pose.position.x = 0;
    data.pose.pose.position.y = 0;
    data.pose.pose.position.z = 0;
    data.twist.twist.linear.x = 0;
    data.twist.twist.linear.y = 0;
    data.twist.twist.linear.z = 0;
    ros::Rate rate(100);
    while (ros::ok())
    {
        pub.publish(data);
        data.pose.pose.position.x += 1.0;
        rate.sleep();
        ros::spinOnce();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

After i run the code, the info output by the callback like this. The difference between the data before and after 1 second is 100, which is correct, but the changes in the data are not continuous, about two-thirds of the data is lost, after I change the published and subscribed data to a simple int type, the info output by the callback was not lost. Could someone tell me why.

```
[ INFO] [1691025304.970631250]: x: 534.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.014777988]: x: 538.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.019294864]: x: 539.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.029349545]: x: 540.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.070614103]: x: 544.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.114707116]: x: 548.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.158679485]: x: 552.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.202648991]: x: 557.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.246669446]: x: 561.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.249411401]: x: 562.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.259341235]: x: 563.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.302654749]: x: 567.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.346705878]: x: 571.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.390708431]: x: 576.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.434621099]: x: 580.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.439409861]: x: 581.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.449302088]: x: 582.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.490661031]: x: 586.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.534639046]: x: 590.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.582676911]: x: 595.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.626683167]: x: 599.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.629425701]: x: 600.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.639365812]: x: 601.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.682694151]: x: 605.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.726678524]: x: 609.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.770639589]: x: 613.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.770734517]: x: 614.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.814676002]: x: 617.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.814776174]: x: 618.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.819332395]: x: 619.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.829267456]: x: 620.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.870585413]: x: 623.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.870677599]: x: 624.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.914597913]: x: 628.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.958604223]: x: 631.000000
[ INFO] [1691025305.958706574]: x: 632.000000
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/418072/when-i-subscribed-to-nav_msgs/odometry-data-which-is-published-at-a-frequency-of-100hz,-the-callback-processed-the-data-slowly-and-the-data-was-lost,-thanks./) by [zyt](https://answers.ros.org/users/168067/zyt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Increase your queue size on the subscriber to ~10, 1 is probably why some get replaced in the queue

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2023-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zyt](https://answers.ros.org/users/168067/zyt/) on 2023-08-05**:
Thank you so much for your endless help！

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Printing the data on the screen is actually not "nothing". It is more time consuming than several other operations that you could do, try storing it to a another variable and print all of them after the designated time. You should be able to receive the data at much higher rates with roscpp. Increasing the queue size should also help in case of sporadic transport fluctuations.

---

Originally posted by [Gaurav Gupta](https://answers.ros.org/users/72874/gaurav-gupta/) with karma: 276 on 2023-08-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zyt](https://answers.ros.org/users/168067/zyt/) on 2023-08-05**:
Thank you so much for your endless help！